# Does Windows Phone 8 support 3rd party C# Libraries?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm writing a signal processing program (invoving FFT's and some filtering) on a desktop PC, I am using the Math.NET Neodym library, and I want this code to be portable to windows phone 8, so I wanted to be sure about whether 3rd party libraries can be used in Windows Phone 8.
I have seen similar questions about windows phone 7.1, but I can't find any info on WP8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP8 can support 3rd party libraries if they were written for the platform. That's really something you have to look at on a per library basis. As Math.NET Neodym library is open source, even if it doesn't compile down to work on WP8, you could probably modify it to